# Saving image in the MongoDB backend with Multer as file from Angular it is not working as excepted

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, typescript, blob

I'm facing with an problem which is at my opinion not working.
I did install a library in angular `cropper.js` `https://github.com/matheusdavidson/angular-cropperjs`
And in the Frontend I am dealing with some code that the developer developed this library.

So my iteration will be like this.

the cropped image will be sent to my api in backend and there to save the files and to show the file in some other place.

The actual crop it saves a link with blob and there is my img.
The post request it works and I can see the img is there in the folder but when I try to get the image the get it works but in the console of frontend it says me that.
`GET http://localhost:4200/images/image-1607708300007.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

But in the `GET` request it is the image there.

```
{"_id":"5fd3bf6f946e9c40163d82f3",
 "imageTitle":"undefined",
 "imageDesc":"undefined",
 "imageUrl":"/images/image-1607712623266.jpg",
 "uploaded":"2020-12-11T18:50:23.288Z","__v":0}
```

But if I try with postman to get this it is not working.
I am trying in postman like this.
`http://localhost:4200/images/image-1607713934301.jpg`it is the same error mesage as in console.

```
`<pre>Cannot GET /images/image-1607713934301.jpg</pre>`
```

If I try to log what the frontend it sends to backend I do have something like.
`console.log(req.file);`

```
   { fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'acf6a796-7b4b-4b12-b429-1d21352f3a45.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: '/Users/abedinzhuniqi/Projects/xxxx/images',
  filename: 'image-1607712623266.jpg',
  path:
   '/Users/abedinzhuniqi/Projects/xxxx/images/image-1607712623266.jpg',
  size: 1540633 }
```

This is my frontend code.
This is the html.

```
<angular-cropper #angularCropper
[cropperOptions]="imgConfig"
 [imageUrl]="imgUrl | safeurl"></angular-cropper>
 <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-upload" for="inputImage" title="Upload image file" >
        <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="inputImage" name="file" accept="image/*" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Import image with Blob URLs">
          <span class="fa fa-upload"></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="crop" title="Crop" (click)="saveImage()">
        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="cropper.crop()">
          <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
```

And this is my TS.

```
  imgUrl = "";
  image: Image;
  imageURL;


   imgConfig = {
    aspectRatio : 3/4,
    dragMode : "move",
    background : true,
    movable: true,
    rotatable : true,
    scalable: true,
    zoomable: true,
    viewMode: 1,
    checkImageOrigin : true,
    checkCrossOrigin: true
};

  fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
  this.imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  this.image = event.target.files[0];
  }
saveImage() {
  console.log(this.image);
   const file = new File([this.imgUrl], this.image.type);
  this.imageService.addImage(this.image, file).subscribe((res: any) => {
    if (res.body) {
     this.imageService.getImageByID(res.body._id).subscribe((t: Image) => {
     this.imageURL = t.imageUrl;
     });
    }
  }, (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

This is the Service

```
export class ImageService {
   apiUrl = environment.backend;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  addImage(image: Image, file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("imageTitle", image.imageTitle);
    formData.append("imageDesc", image.imageDesc);
    const header = new HttpHeaders();
    const params = new HttpParams();

    const options = {
      params,
      reportProgress: true,
      headers: header
    };
    const req = new HttpRequest("POST", this.apiUrl, formData, options);
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
  getImageByID(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Image>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): any {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

}
```

And my backend API looks like this.

```
    const multer  = require('multer');
    const Image = require("../models/image");


    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log(cb);
      cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '../../../../images'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      var filetype = '';
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/gif') {
        filetype = 'gif';
      }
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        filetype = 'png';
      }
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
        filetype = 'jpg';
      }
      cb(null, 'image-' + Date.now() + '.' + filetype);
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage: storage});
routes.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Image.findById(req.params.id, function (err, gallery) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(gallery);
    });
});
  
// post data
routes.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.file) {
        return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Upload fail'});
    } else {
        req.body.imageUrl = req.file.filename;
        Image.create(req.body, function (err, image) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            }
            res.json(image);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You might be using `URL.createObjectURL()` when getting the cropped image. Instead you need the image in a blob format to upload is to the server. You can use `toDataUrl()` function to get the blob.

Comment: @AliWahab how would be that possible ?

Comment: What are you using for cropping your image?

Comment: I am using that library see the ling of github.

Comment: Can you verify your API is working on postman?

Comment: @AliWahab My API it works, but  not sending the img there.

Comment: You can't send image from postman as well?

Comment: @AliWahab No, in postman at the POST it is returningme back the link something like this.
`/Users/abedinzhuniqi/Projects/my-project/backend/src/app/controllers/img/cv.png`

Comment: @AliWahab I have changed some code see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server should send image content. Currently you respond with only JSON which contains path to image, but not an image itself. To do so you need add [static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) file middleware:

```js
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), '../images'))
```

Then you should make your host produce correct URLs you'll need to update the object you return from server like this:

```js
routes.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Image.findById(req.params.id, function (err, gallery) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json({
            ...gallery.toJSON(),
            imageUrl: `//${req.host}:${req.port}/${gallery.imageUrl}`,
        });
    });
});
```

Thus you'll serve you static content and receive correct URLs on the frontend side.

Comment: @PaulRumnik how to send the content ?

Comment: I am having the same error in the HTML.
 `http://localhost:4200/images/image-1607871519730.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi express.static will do it for you. You only need to be sure a) images are getting to images folder (with file manager) b) requests to image (e.g. `/images/picture.png`) passing well (with browser).

Comment: Do I need to add the folder into backend folder or I can do it outside ?
I tried it but it is saying me the same error in angular.
I didnt understand what you meant with file manager ?

Comment: I mean you should upload a file with the code you've created and then to make sure the uploading works and the file is getting in destination folder on server. To make sure you can open file manager and check if there is a new file in images `/Users/abedinzhuniqi/Projects/xxxx/images/` folder. If it so, then express.static should solve the problem. If there is no file, then the problem is in other part of your code.

Comment: I have deleted all images and added new one and there is the new img what I have added.
But  still having the problem.
I have added the `static` as you said.
`app.use('/images', express.static('../images'));` but it is not working again.
In the folder there are images what I have saved.

Comment: I think that angular it does not read the img outside his assets ?

Comment: Are you sure '../images' is the proper path to the folder? Note that this path is relative to `process.cwd()` not to `__dirname`. If it is correct, then you can open the url `http://localhost:4200/images/picture.jpg` in a browser (where `picture.png` should be replaced with some actual image file name), and you should see the image. Do you see this image?

Comment: I will check it and will give u info.

Comment: I tried to call `http://localhost:4200/images/picture.jpg` and it does not find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225906/discussion-between-abedin-zhuniqi-and-paul-rumkin).

Comment: I need more little bit your help would u be able to help me ?

Comment: Wrote to the chat.